# i need help in item check in tool strip menu item

Tags: vb.net, toolstripitem

i got a column here..what i'm trying to do is when i select an item

[image]

i want the item in the context menu to be check according to the status in the column

[image]

here's what im trying so far

```
 Dim currentItem As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim parentItem = DirectCast(currentItem.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
    For Each ctl As ToolStripMenuItem In parentItem.DropDownItems
        If TypeOf ctl Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
            If ctl.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text Then
                currentItem = DirectCast(ctl, ToolStripMenuItem)
                currentItem.Checked = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

but just gives me nothing..how can i turn this around ? been struggling with this since last night..tnx in advance

Comment: *just gives me an error* is not a problem description. What *specific error* does it give you? That information is available to you, and there's no reason you shouldn't include it in your question so that we have it as well. If you call your auto repair shop and say *My car makes a funny noise. How can I fix it?*, they're not going to help without more information about the noise. If you want us to help you, provide the details you have; we can't see your screen or read your mind from where we sit.

Comment: Sorry there, mate, but changing from *just gives me error* to *just gives me nothing* is not an update. Use the debugger, and figure out where the problem is, and then you can ask about that problem. **If you want us to help you, provide the details you have.** If you can't do that, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: i change this.."If ctl.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text" and it gives me nothing..just like the 2nd pic from the above..sir..if i select an item and the listview and right click to open the context menu..it gives me nothing..i hope that's clear for u sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions to your issue. The first is based more on your original code, which I wasn't 100% sure which event you were targeting so I couldn't test it:

```
    Dim currentItem As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim parentItem = DirectCast(currentItem.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
    For Each ctl As ToolStripMenuItem In parentItem.DropDownItems
        If ctl.Text = "Status" Then
            For Each dropctl As ToolStripMenuItem In ctl.DropDownItems
                If dropctl.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text Then
                    dropctl.Checked = True
                Else
                    dropctl.Checked = False ' Ensure that you uncheck a previously checked status
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Next is the actual code that I used to test this functionality. I used the Opening event for the context menu to make this work. This may not work for you if you are reusing the same context menu for different columns or controls but if not then I would recommend this approach:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Opening(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip1.Opening
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For Each ctl As ToolStripMenuItem In CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip).Items
            If ctl.Text = "Status" Then
                For Each dropctl As ToolStripMenuItem In ctl.DropDownItems
                    If dropctl.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text Then
                        dropctl.Checked = True
                    Else
                        dropctl.Checked = False ' Ensure that you uncheck a previously checked status
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
        e.Cancel = True   ' Don't show the context menu if no row was clicked on
    End If
End Sub
```

In your original code you were only looping through the parent menu items. In this updated code it looks for the parent item 'Status' and then loops through the child items to find the status you need to check.

Comment: woooah ! a many thanks there sir ! aaaah..you just save my life..coz now i can finally sleep in peace..been struggling with that since last night..thank god u bring an angel of programming to help those in needs..tnx tnx tnx